# error for object 0x7c15bad4: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

I am working with sockets and writing some data to server. The first time when it makes connection to the server everything works fine. But when it writes the second and sometimes third time it crashes with the error:

```
"malloc: *** error for object 0x7c15bad4: incorrect checksum for freed
object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"
```

And it crashes on these lines:

```
var response:NSString = NSString(format: "%@",dataString)
var data:NSData = NSData(data: response.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!)
data.getBytes(&socket.sharedInstance.byteData)
socket.sharedInstance.outputStream.write(byteData, maxLength: data.length)
```

Mostly on the last line. I have declared the variables globally. And I have no clue what is happening. I have added the Symbolic Breakpoint but of no success. I am using XCode 6.0 and Swift.

Further investigation reveals this:

```
(36729,0xb0115000) malloc: protecting edges
(36729,0xb0115000) malloc: enabling scribbling to detect mods to free blocks
(36729,0xb0115000) malloc: purgeable zone does not support guard pages
(36729,0xb0115000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region securely
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Comment: is byteData same as sharedInstance.byteData ?
what if :
socket.sharedInstance.outputStream.write(data.bytes(), maxLength: data.length)

Comment: So should I use data.bytes() instead of byteData?

Comment: Nah you might use byteData, but just strange that in last line you use just byteData and in previous you use sharedInstance.byteData, not sure if it's same field ?

Comment: Yes I have tried by both approaches but same thing happens.

Comment: If you remove the 3rd line, and use data.bytes() does it still crash ?. Something wrong in the pointers, might not be even in this code you posted but in other thread.

Comment: Any other clue you can give @Krysztof

Comment: Not really :/ try commenting stuff out, as i said earlier it might happen in different code, if it's multithread app.

Comment: If I use data.bytes() then it does not compile gives error. "Cannot convert UnsafePointer<Void> to UnsafePointer<UInt8>"

Comment: Yes it is a multi threaded application. I will work on your suggestion

Comment: Try casting it to UnsafePointer<UInt8>

Comment: And How to do that? :)

Comment: Something like UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes()) ?

Comment: It works Please add this as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this code:

```
var response:NSString = NSString(format: "%@",dataString)
var data:NSData = NSData(data: response.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!)
socket.sharedInstance.outputStream.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes()) , maxLength: data.length)
```

Think that the byteData might not be initialized with correct size.